# How to get F# project templates in Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 RC?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, f#

With Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 RC 
I can open existing F# projects but can't create new. 
Repaired FSharp_Bundle (F# Tools 3.1.1) but it made no effect.

So how to get F# project templates in Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 RC?

Comment: Could you detail exactly why you can't create a new project?  Are the templates not showing up in the list of projects to create?  Do you get an exception when you try to create one?

Comment: @mydogisbox templates not showing up in the list of projects to create

Comment: I have not tried the RC but most likely it's a similar problem you get with Websharper - the solution there was to insert certain keys into the registry (indeed Websharper projects ship with a .fsi that does just this ;) ) - as I cannot really tell you what you have to insert the best advice I can give is to go and file in a Bug

Comment: When I create a new F# project, within the New Project dialog, the templates are under `Installed>Templates>Other Languages>Visual F#`. At what point does this break down for you?

Comment: Hi, I have exactly the same symptoms with F#3.1.2 and VS2013.5 (Installed > Templates > Other Langugages > Visual F# is empty, but I can stil open and run F# projects). Did you find the solution?

Comment: @MiloszKrajewski this question was asked more than year ago, currently I have VS Community and it works there...